# How to refresh a table row in a JSON request using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have written my first AJAX request to set the value in a table to 1 if the file is a "redline". If the value is 1 when the page loads, the filename should be displayed in red (a simple if statement). The AJAX request works fine and the value in the table gets changed to 1, but I'm not sure how to refresh the row in the table without refreshing the whole page.

This is my first AJAX request, so please be patient.

Here is the AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function markAsRedline(attachmentid) {
        new Request.JSON({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('job/markAsRedline'); ?>/' + attachmentid,
            onSuccess:
                // refresh table row
        }).send();
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the table row to be updated:

```
<tr id="attrow2104461" class="even">
    <td><span title="ABC">ABC (65)</span></td>
    <td><input style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" type="text" name="description" class="description" size="42"><img src="##/img/redline.png" height="17px" title="Mark as redline" onclick="markAsRedline(2104461);"></td>
    <td><a href="###" data-attid="2104461">resfds.docx</a></td> <!-- This is where the text should change color -->
</tr>
```

I have no idea where to go from here. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Add your HTML, it will help us help you. You can easily add a css class to change the color of the table row to red without any type of page refresh. It's not clear to me why you think a page refresh would be necessary. Maybe there's information about this you have not provided?

Comment: I will add the HTML. I do not think a page refresh would be necessary, just to be clear - I want to avoid that.

Comment: `onSuccess: { document.getElementById('attrow2104461').className += ' text-red'; }` or `onSuccess: { document.getElementById('attrow2104461').style.backgroundColor = 'red';` Either of these (as well as other ways not shown) could change the color of the table row on success of the service call. You can do the same thing by identifying just the column that displays the file name. Do you know how to select that column? Is your goal to change the whole row or just the file name column?

Comment: @daddygames, thank you. My goal is to just change the file name column.  Yes, I know how to select that column. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @daddygames, can you post your answer as an answer so I can accept? Also, how would I add another line to this? Make it a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onSuccess` property of `Request.JSON` is a function call that is triggered when the ajax call successfully returns with data. You have several options for how to deal with this.

**EXAMPLE 1**

Let's say you break out the color change into it's own method like so:

```
let markAsRedLine = (responseJSON, responseText) => {
  // let's assume the response contains the attachmentid we need
  // select the element on the page with the attachmentid
  let el = document.querySelector('[data-attid="' + responseJSON.attachmentid + '"]');
  // style the element's text color as RED
  el.style.color = 'red';
}
```

Now, when you make your AJAX call, you can assign the `onSuccess` property so that it calls the `markAsRedLine` function.

```
new Request.JSON({
  url: '<?php echo site_url('job/markAsRedline'); ?>/' + attachmentid,
  onSuccess: markAsRedLine
}).send();
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

You may not care what the result of the AJAX call is and so this next example ignores that information and just uses the attachmentid that is passed from the input element:

```
new Request.JSON({
  url: '<?php echo site_url('job/markAsRedline'); ?>/' + attachmentid,
  onSuccess: function(responseJSON, responseText) { // notice function definition
    let el = document.querySelector('[data-attid="' + attachmentid+ '"]');
    el.style.color = 'red'
  }
}).send();
```

You could also break this out in the same way as the first example:

```
function makeRed(attachmentid) {
  let el = document.querySelector('[data-attid="' + attachmentid+ '"]');
  el.style.color = 'red'
}

new Request.JSON({
  url: '<?php echo site_url('job/markAsRedline'); ?>/' + attachmentid,
  onSuccess: function(responseJSON, responseText) { // notice function definition
    makeRed(attachmentid);
  }
}).send();
```

In that example, you need to implement the `onSuccess` function as defined by the API so as not to break it, then inside that function make the call to style your elements.

**EXAMPLE 3**

In the next example, you can see how to do this without using an AJAX call:

```js
function markAsRedline(attachmentid) {
  var el = document.querySelector('[data-attid="' + attachmentid + '"]');
  el.style.color = 'red';
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="attrow2104461" class="even">
    <td><span title="ABC">ABC (65)</span></td>
    <td><input style="background-color: transparent; border: none;" type="text" name="description" class="description" size="42"><img src="https://otb.cachefly.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/red-line.png" height="17px" /></td>
    <td><a href="###" data-attid="2104461">resfds.docx</a></td> <!-- This is where the text should change color -->
  </tr>
</table>
 
<button type="button" onclick="markAsRedline('2104461');">Mark as Red</button>
```

MooTools offers some decent documentation on `Request.JSON` here -> **https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Request/Request.JSON**